# How to format figure numbering as X-Y when section numbering is formatted as X.0?

Tags: floats, sectioning, numbering

I've used the following commands in my document to ensure that section numbering appears as 1.0, etc. while the subsections appear as 1.1, 1.2, etc.:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

However, I want the figures to be formatted as 1-1, 1-2, etc., so I used the following command:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
```

But of course, this appears as 1.0-1, 1.0-2, etc.

So my question: is there a way to keep the section numbering as X.0 while the figure numbering appears as X-1, X-2, etc. (i.e., without the decimal zero)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}` the `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}` will gives what you like to obtain.

Comment: Zarko answered your question, but I do not recommend a `1.0` section numbering.

Comment: @Zarko That seems to do the trick! Thank you! Seems to mess up my appendix figure numbering though. I suppose I can force a new style in that section specifically.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't like the numbering, but it's a format I need to stick to for the report I'm writing.

Comment: @FadingBuffers: I see -- it's strange anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have somewhere defined `\thesection` on different way as you expected. So if you instead

```
 \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
```

use

```
 \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}
```

you will obtain desired form of figure numbers.